# How do I get the sock fd of the client while receiving the message using zmq_msg_recv()?

Tags: zeromq

I am using ZMQ `zmq_msg_recv()` for receiving client connections and requests,  How do I get the sock fd of the client who has sent this message?
I have read somewhere that this feature is added in ZMQ 4 but somehow not able to locate which API gives the sock fd
Any pointers in this regards?

Comment: Are you the same Bharat that asked the same question on the ZeroMQ mailing list? If so, I think Doron provided an answer pointing to ZMQ_SRCFD which is deprecated and saying that currently there is no other way in version 4.

Comment: Yes, I am the same Bharat :)  Yes, explored other API's also - right now there is no support of Identity property for PUSH/PULL type of sockets. SRC_FD will not help if client processes are on same system.